# Как обрамить кавычками значение без отступов при интерполяции строк в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Следующий шаблон:

```
'module: "{module:10s}"; file: "{filename:10s}"; line: "{lineno:3d}"; msg: "{message}";'
```

Соответствует строке:

```
module: "views     "; file: "views.py  "; line: " 62"; msg: "text";
```

Какой шаблон с **отступами** соответствует строке(?):

```
module: "views";      file: "views.py";   line: "62";  msg: "text";
```

Comment: Ну например что-то типа `'module: {module:10s} file: {filename:10s} line: {lineno:3s} msg: {message}'`, только в строках нужно подготовить значения с кавычками и точками с запятой. Не понятно только зачем такое нужно.

Comment: Я не могу изменить значения этих переменных, они приходят из другого модуля. Я могу лишь указать строку форматирования. Это нужно чтобы обозначить границы значений в случае машинной интерпретации логов.

Comment: Так, а при машинной интерпретации точки с запятой невозможно использовать как границы значений?

Comment: Я могу гарантировать отсутствие кавычек в переменных, но не отсутствие точек с запятой. Я также хотел бы знать, если эту задачу нельзя решить только лишь при помощи изменения шаблона, как указанно в вопросе.

Comment: Ну вот на коленке с помощью модуля [parse](https://pypi.org/project/parse/) я разобрал строку, где и точки с запятой и кавычки внутри строк встречаются: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiOsj.png . Дополнительные пробелы - это какие-то костыли. На самом деле, такое в принципе можно и с помощью регулярных выражений распарсить.

Comment: Ссылку рубит файерволл в моём офисе. Покажите регулярку, пожалуйста

Comment: Дополнительные пробелы - это не костыли. Это законный способ структуризации произвольного текста по столбцам, предусмотренного методами интерполяции, что очень полезно для лога и глаз админа. Скажите, если считаете, что я не прав.

Comment: Для глаз админа - допустим, для парсинга - без разницы сколько там пробелов будет, это без проблем можно распарсить. Даже регуляркой. Регулярку я прямо сейчас не напишу, но если сильно нужно будет, могу позже сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Средствами форматирования/интерполяции то что вы хотите нормально вряд ли получится сделать. Я бы просто пробелы после точек с запятой заменил на табы, потом уже к отформатированной строке применял метод строки `expandtabs`:

```
format_string = 'module: "{module}";\tfile: "{filename}";\tline: "{lineno}";\tmsg: "{message}";'

module = "views"
filename = "views.py"
lineno = 62
message = "text"

formatted = format_string.format(module=module, filename=filename, lineno=lineno, message=message)
print(formatted)  # вывод с табами, результат зависит от настроек размера табуляции терминала / редактора и т.д.
print(formatted.expandtabs())  # по умолчанию tab заменяется выравниванием под 8 символов
print(formatted.expandtabs(32))  # выравнивание под 32 символа
```

Примерный вывод:

```
module: "views";    file: "views.py";   line: "62"; msg: "text";
module: "views";        file: "views.py";       line: "62";     msg: "text";
module: "views";                file: "views.py";               line: "62";                     msg: "text";
```

Выравнивание под N символов означает, что кусок после символа табуляции будет выровнен под ближайшую позицию от начала строки, кратную N.

Например для таба размером 8:

```
module: "views";        file: "views.py";       line: "62";     msg: "text";
                 ^14    ^32               ^42   ^48         ^60 ^64
```

Первый маркер в каждой паре - позиция, на которой могла продолжиться строка при табе = 1 пробелу, видно что каждый раз число не кратно 8. Второй маркер - позиция строки после "развертки" табов, строка становится сдвинута так, чтобы позиция стала кратной 8.